# Use of unresolved identifier 'self' in Swift 5

Tags: swift

I wanted to write a weather app using OpenWeatherMap Api. Everything looks fine for me. The app was written using an tutorial on the web and everything looks 1:1.

````
let weatherURL = URL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Warsaw,pl?&units=imperial&APPID=cb9325925ed023b38a64c3d8da3c345c")!
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: weatherURL) {
    (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error:\n\(error)")
    } else {
        if let data = data {
            let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            print("All the weather data:\n\(dataString!)")
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                if let mainDictionary = jsonObj.value(forKey: "main") as? NSDictionary {
                    if let temperature = mainDictionary.value(forKey: "temp") {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.weatherLabel.text = "Temperatura w Warszawie: \(temperature)°C"
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Error: unable to find temperature in dictionary")
                }
            } else {
                print("Error: unable to convert json data")
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code

```
let weatherURL = ...
let dataTask = ...
```

...needs to be inside some *method* of some struct or class. If you look at the original tutorial, you'll see that that's the case. Your code is just hanging out loose in the open, in a place where executable code is not permitted.

Comment: Also your tutorial is old and uses some outmoded features. JSONSerialization is pretty much dead at this point.